# Target daily ROI for a market-making algorithm

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, market-making, algorithmic-trading

I'm designing a market-making algorithm, I was wondering what a decent ROI / day would be to aim for in such a system?

Comment: Aim for something > 0%.

Comment: Some additional research suggests that 1% might be optimistic for a daily ROI.

Comment: Dude, you are way too late to the game. The show has long moved on from equities to currencies. And when designing strategies, in case you ever managed risk and traded, you do not start out with how much return you may achieve. That is what your research should tell you. "Don't count your chickens before they've hatched"

Comment: Hey forgot to mention, your ROI will also be tied heavily to transaction costs + margin req, which depends on your exchange membership/negotiation with the direct access broker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best options AMM guys are rumored to capture roughly 1/3tick per round trip, net of transaction costs + implementation shortfalls. I had worked for a regional index options MM. With the growth of competition in the recent years, expected returns are actually much lower than that today.

So realistically, in today's environment, you could net maybe 1/5tick per round trip. Estimate the average number of round trips expected per day, and you have all variables needed to work out ROI. good luck.

Comment: OP, could you show some basic respect and upvote answers, particularly those you marked as correct?

Comment: I would love to, but I need a certain number of points before I'm allowed to, which is looking impossible since this question has been down-voted so much :)